# Uncaught TypeError: Liferay.NotificationsList is not a constructor I am getting in browser while deploying extjs application in liferay

Tags: exception, extjs, liferay, extjs6

I am using Extjs version 6 and Liferay 6.2.5 when I am deploying application in Liferay I am getting above exception in browser.

[image: e]

Comment: Add that class to your requires list

Comment: can you please specify where exactly i have to add it. i mean file name and place

Comment: Do you have the notification portlet deployed? Do you use it?

Answer (score 0):

(*I think Piyush must have resolved it by now, posting it, if anyone else is facing the same issue.*)

You need to import liferay-notification js module to use Liferay Notifications.
example:

```
<aui:script use="liferay-notification"> 
    new Liferay.Notification({
        closeable: true,
        delay: {
            hide: 3000,
            show: 0,
        },
        duration: 500,
        message: message,
        title: 'Your success Message',
        type: 'success'
        //danger, warning and info also exists
    }).render();
</aui:script>
```

another way is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    AUI().use('liferay-notification', function(A) {
        new Liferay.Notification({
            closeable: true,
            delay: {
                hide: 10000,
                show: 0
            },
            duration: 500,
            message: message,
            render: true,
            title: 'your success message',
            type: 'success'
        }).render('body');
    });
</script>
```